# discord.py on_member_update remove all roles member has

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanna remove all roles a member has when its `if game_after`

How can I do `for role in member.roles: await member.remove_roles(role)` here?

I get `404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role` when I do `for role in member.roles: await member.remove_roles(role)`

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    
        if game_after:
            game_name = game_after[0].name.strip()
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            await after.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: What's difficult about it? You answered your own question lol

Comment: I know but I tried this after `if game_after` `for role in before.roles: await before.remove_roles(role)` it doesnt work and it breaks the code

Comment: Then add that code and add the error

Comment: and when I do `for role in before.roles: print(role)` I get the list of roles. so I dont know why `before.remove_roles(role)` isn't working here

Comment: Because you're supposed to remove the roles of the `after` instance

Comment: that's the error I got from `if game_after for role in before.roles: await before.remove_roles(role)` 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role

Comment: I see.. okay I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you tried to remove the everyone role, so idk if this is what you want now but you can configure it:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    
        if game_after:
            game_name = game_after[0].name.strip()
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            roles = after.roles[1:]
            await after.remove_role(*roles)
```